# Minimizing with requirejs an application that contains slickgrid has errors because of css and images

Tags: css, slickgrid

I've been starting to use slick grid yesterday and I don't know how to resolve or what is the easiest thing to do. My app hierarchy:

```
 - production
    - index.html
    - build.css
    - img <- images are here
 - src
   - assets
      - css <- here are my css
      - img <- here are my images
   - vendor
      - SlickGrid/css/smoothness/
            - images <- images for slickgrid
            - jquery-ui.....css <- this is the css for the slickgrid
```

Now the build process will compile all the css in one big css named build css and copies the img folder to the production.

The problem is that the jquery-ui.....css provided in the slickgrid has a different reference to the images. For example if there is an image named `sexy` the `slickgrid.css` will call it like this: `images/sexy` instead of the required: `img/sexy`;

In fact the optimize changes the path for example of `image/sexy` to `../../vendor/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/images/sexy`.

How do I fix this? thanks

Comment: you have to change the images path in css file or cut paste the related images to the related folder...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I didn't saw the optimize whole project the other day, so in my case I should do the optimize the whole project. This will copy all the files from the ´src´ to ´production´ and will build paths relative to the new files.
My build.js in this case is:

```
{
appDir: ".",
dir: "../production",
baseUrl: ".",
name: "main",
//out: "../production/build.js",
optimize: "none",
paths: {
     "jquery": "vendor/jquery-1.9.1"
    ,"jquery-ui": "vendor/jquery-ui.min"
    ,"bootstrap": "vendor/bootstrap.min"
    ,"slick.grid": "vendor/SlickGrid/slick.grid"
    ,"slick.core": "vendor/SlickGrid/slick.core"
    ,"jquery.event.drag": "vendor/jqueryPlugins/jquery.event.drag-2.2"
},
shim: {
     "jquery": []
    ,"jquery-ui": ['jquery']
    ,"bootstrap": { deps: ["jquery"] }
    ,"slick.grid": ["jquery", "jquery.event.drag", "slick.core"]
    ,"slick.core": ["jquery", "jquery.event.drag"]
    ,"jquery.event.drag": ["jquery"]
}
 }
```

And I call it from a batch file in win like this (which stays in the root):

```
call node src/vendor/r.js -o src/build2.js
pause
```